# Create shortcut to console.log() in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, shortcut

Because I'm lazy, I created a function `log` that basically is just an abbreviation of `console.log`:

```
function log() {
  console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

Whenever I call this, I see the logged item in Google Chrome's Developer Tools, with on the right hand side the line number where the item was logged. However, this line number is always the same, because the actual `console.log` call is located at one specific place in the code (namely where I declare the `log` function as above).

What I also tried is just:

```
var log = console.log;
```

but this always throws an error: `Illegal invocation`. Weird, but I guess that's not a possibility.

How can I make a shortcut to `console.log`, with Developer Tools showing the line number where `log` was called, rather than where the actual `console.log` call is located?

Comment: log does not work because the global object (window) does not have a log method.  I very much doubt that what you want to do is possible. But I would be interested to be proven wrong.

Comment: @Hand B PUFAL: Excuse me if I'm wrong, but I declared my own `log()` function as above, so that I can call it with just `log()`. So it does work, except the fact that the position displayed is not what I'd like it to show.

Comment: I don't have `Illegal Invocation` error for console but have for `document`, for example for `document.getElementById`. I found some explanation here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229797/illegal-invocation-with-javascript)
but I don't understand why it does't work in the same document.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

When I reported it, it was refused but the answer was simple - create the shortcut like this:

```
var log = console.log.bind(console);
```

This doesn't leave out the line number, whilst you can call it like `log(...)`.

Comment: is this permanent or when i close and open chrome it will be gone?

Comment: @pimvdb:  Any workarounds to get the line number too.

Comment: the best way I've seen. I want to add, that to disable logging for some function it is possible to write:
`const $=0; $ && log('hello javascript');`

Answer (score 5):

I just created a module to do that.

Check out: https://github.com/ahlechandre/consl

#### Install

`npm install consl --save-dev`

#### Usage

```
const { cl } = require('consl');

cl('Outputs a message on the Console using a quick');
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I've set up an AutoHotKey shortcut with Ctrl + Alt + L as below:

```
^!l::Send console.log();{Left}{Left}
```

The good thing is it brings the cursor back inside the brackets for quick typing.

Answer (score 1):

Tried a few things, but I don't think you can do this. As soon as you wrap `console.log`, the line nr will be the line where this wrap is to be found in the code. I suppose we have to live with that then?

Comment: You can always try, it's an understandable need. I don't think it will get a high priority ranking @Chromium though ;~).