# javascript send arguments object as argument

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments

I need to pass arguments onto a callback function as real arguments. How do I do that? callback requires a variable number of arguments.

Example function like this:

```
var func = function (callback) {
  doSomething(function () {
    // the goal is to pass on the arguments object to the callback function as real arguments
    callback(arguments)
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

It might be a similar question to this:
[Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments to a JavaScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/is-it-possible-to-send-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-javascript-function)

But I didn't understand that question nor the answers.

Edit: If possible, I would like to not pollute global.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) to invoke the callback so the array items gets passed as individual arguments to the function.

```
callback.apply(this, arguments);
```

`apply` takes the context, and an array as an argument, and each item of the array can be passed as a named argument of the function being invoked.

```
function two(first, second) {
    alert(first), alert(second);
}

two.apply(null, ["Hello", "World"]); // alerts "Hello", then "World"
```

Implementations of ES3 required that the second argument to `apply` be either an array, or an arguments object. ES5 makes it more liberal in that as long as it resembles an array - has a `length` property, and corresponding integer indexes, it will work.

Comment: Why apply null instead of this?

Comment: allpy takes two arguments, the obejct which becomes this in the called function and an array whic becmes the arguments. So your line should read callback.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));

Comment: Yep, I've messed up with this before seeing your answer came up with something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/HYTJL/

Comment: I'm not using `this` in any special manner inside the function `two`, so it doesn't really matter what we pass as context to `apply`. We could've passed in anything - `two.apply("dontCare", ["Hello", "World"])`.

Comment: @Hans - thanks for the correction, I'm missing the context as the first argument.

Comment: The question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456709/create-shortcut-to-console-log confirmsthat slicing and dicing is not necessary : just need callback.apply (this, arguments);

Comment: @Hans @Harry - If you are passing an array or the arguments object as the second parameter to apply, then you should be fine as per the specs in ECMAScript 3rd ed [(sec 15.3.4.3)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf). For ECMAScript 5th ed [(sec 15.3.4.3)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), anything that looks like an array - has a length property, and integer indexes corresponding to the length, should work.