# How do I pass console.log as an argument to my JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

In the code below I can use print in place of console.log and the program can run correctly.  However I wish to use console.log but I get

> Illegal invocation

at runtime

```
function forEach(array, action) {
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
        action(array[i]);
}

forEach(["blah", "bac"], console.log);
```

Comment: It will work if you pass only the `console` and call `log` inside the forEach function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In general you can't pass methods directly to callbacks in Javascript.** The `this` is bound at the point of the function call, depending on what form you call it and there is no automatic binding of methods (like there is in, for example, Python)

```
//does not work.
var obj = {
    x: 17,
    f: function(){ return this.x; }
};

//inside doSomething, f forgets its "this" should be obj
doSomething( obj.f )
```

In these cases, one might use `Function.prototype.bind` (or a similar function from your library of choice, since `bind` is not present in IE <= 8)

```
//works (for normal methods - see next bit for console.log in particular)
var obj = {
    x: 17,
    f: function(){ return this.x; }
};

doSomething( obj.f.bind(obj) )
```

**Unfortunately, however, this is not always enough for console.log.** Since it is not an actual Function in IE, (its an evil host object) you cannot use bind, apply and call methods on it on that browser so the only workaround is falling back to wrapping the call in an anonymous function

```
doSomething( function(x){
    return console.log(x);
});
```

Since wrapping console.log in an anonymous function is long and annoying to type I usually add the following global function when I'm developing and debugging:

```
function log(message){ return function(x){
    return console.log(message, x);
};};

forEach(['asd', 'zxc'], log('->'));
```

Answer (score 4):

From here : [Create shortcut to console.log() in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456709/create-shortcut-to-console-log)

You can replace `console.log` with `console.log.bind(console)`

**Explanation thanks to @julian-d :**

> Because the `console.log` will refer internally to `this` and expects it
>   to be `console`. If you 'detach' the `log` method e.g. like `var log =
>   console.log`, this association is lost and this will no longer point to
>   `console` (in this case to `window` instead - if you are in a browser).
>   This is the purpose of `.bind(obj)`: it returns a method where
>   internally `this` stays fixed to `obj`.

Comment: but why can't you do `log = console.log` then ?

Comment: @meze: because the `console.log` will refer internally to `this` and expects it to be `console`. If you 'detach' the `log` method e.g. like `var log = console.log`, this association is lost and `this` will no longer point to `console` (in this case to `window` instead - if you are in a browser). This is the purpose of `.bind(obj)`: it returns a method where  internally `this` stays fixed to `obj`.

Comment: Remember that `bind` isn't available in all browsers. See the answer from @frm for a solution that doesn't require `bind`.

Comment: This doesnt not work on IE (the old ones at least) - console.log isn't a Function so it lacks bbind call and apply

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem using an anonymous function acting as a bridge between `forEach()` and `console.log()`

```
forEach(["blah", "bac"], function (element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

Your `forEach()` remains agnostic about the handler and you don't have to juggle with `bind()` to pass a working reference to `console.log()`.