# Passing process.stdout.write directly vs through callback gives different output?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not quite sure why this is happening, however I have the following which I wrote:

```
const runScript = (cmd, args) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // spawn a new process
    const ls = spawn(cmd, args);

    ls.stdout.on("data", (data) => {process.stdout.write(data)});

    ls.stderr.on("data", (data) => {process.stderr.write(data)});

    ls.on("close", code => {
      console.log(`Command ${cmd} ${args} exited with code ${code}`);
      code === 0 ? res(code) : rej(code);
    });

    ls.on("error", code => {
      rej(code);
    });
  });
};
```

This works fine. But I figured I could change the `.on("data")` event handlers to just pass in the write function directly. So I switched from

```
ls.stdout.on("data", (data) => {process.stdout.write(data)});
```

To

```
ls.stdout.on("data", process.stdout.write);
```

Depending on the command, I either get no output with the refactored version (passing `.write` directly) or an EPIPE. I thought they were the exact same.  What's happening exactly here? I'm suspecting it has something to do with either the buffering or what `process` is referring to.

Comment: I hope, this question will help you. It's based on the same concept. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9052329/3439731

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `process.stdout.write` as an argument, it reads the value of `process.stdout.write` and passes JUST the function pointer to the `write` method.  Then, when `ls.staout.on()` calls that method sometime later, it's not bound to `process.stdout` and it does not work properly.

Instead, change to this:

```
ls.stdout.on("data", process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout));
```

And, it will be properly bound to the desired object when it is called.

See [How this is set inside a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016664/when-you-pass-this-as-an-argument/28016676#28016676) for a summary of how `this` is controlled inside a function.

---

As a bit simpler example, see this:

```
class X {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    add(otherVal) {
       return this.val + otherVal;
    }
}

let x = new X(3);
let fn = x.add;
fn(5);               // doesn't work properly
```

Examples of things that would work properly:

```
let x = new X(3);
x.add(5);       // obj.method() sets proper value of this to obj in the method
```

Or, if you want to pass around the method:

```
let x = new X(3);
let fn = x.add;
fn.call(x, 5);   // fn.call(x) artificially sets this to x inside the method
```

Or this:

```
let x = new X(3);
let fn = x.add.bind(x);  // creates stub function that calls method properly
fn(5);
```

This won't work either because when `fn(5)` is called, there's no binding to the `x` object so when the function runs, the reference to `this` inside the `add()` method won't have a proper value of `this` and it won't work properly.

When this code does `let fn = x.add`, it gets a pointer to the `add` method, but there's no binding to the `x` object.  That gets lost.  Then, when you call `fn(5)`, since the `this` value in Javascript is set according to how a function is called, this is just an ordinary function call so the `this` value is set to `undefined` (in strict mode) or the global object (when not in strict mode).  In either case, it's not the desired `x` object.  To make it the `x` object, it has to be called as `x.fn()` of the `this` value has to be artificially set some other method such as with `.apply()`, `.call()` or `.bind()`.

In your case above, since you don't control the caller of the function (it's being called by other code that you don't control), then `.bind()` is an appropriate solution.

Comment: @rb612 - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.  If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.