# javascript console in browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create shortcut to console.log()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456709/create-shortcut-to-console-log)

In javascript we can easy assign functions to variables, eg :

```
a = function(){ alert("hello world");}
b = a;
```

Now both a and b can be interchangeably used to generate an alert message.

But when creating a cross browser console wrapper, I noticed a very peculiar behaviour in chrome :

```
x = console.log
```

now when I use :

```
x("hello world")
```

I get :

```
TypeError : Illegal invocation
```

However the above example works perfectly fine in firefox.

Is this some sort of security related issue with chrome or something altogether different. On a sidenote, is there a way I can get a function which generates an output to browser console with the line number where the function was called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method assignments like in your example lose their `this` context.

Try...

```
var x = console.log.bind(console);
```

Comment: Right... should have been obvious :) Thanks.