# Illegal Invocation with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
var doThis = function(callback){
     callback('google.com');
}
```

If I do this, it works:

```
doThis(alert);
```

But if I do this, I get an error:

```
doThis(window.location.replace);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

I'm building a wrapper for AJAX calls and I need to support functions like `alert`, custom functions, as well as `window.location.replace`.  What am I doing wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/32LJf/1/

Comment: because you're passing the function stored in the window.location.replace property, meaning the context of the function is now `window` rather than `location` therefore it fails.

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery?

Comment: Cuz I am tired. Good night @rlemon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you store a function in a different context than it was intended, it will no longer have access to the properties it had access to previously. For example:

```
var myObj = {
    foo: "foo",
    alert: function(){
        alert(this.foo);
    }
}

myObj.alert(); // "foo"
var a = myObj.alert;
a(); // undefined.
```

when executing the alert function as a property of myObj, it has access to this.foo, however, when you store that function somewhere else, it no longer has access to it. to solve it, store an anonymous function that executes the function instead.

```
var myObj = {
    foo: "foo",
    alert: function(){
        alert(this.foo);
    }
}

myObj.alert(); // "foo"
var a = function(){myObj.alert();}
a(); // "foo".
```

and applied to your code:

```
doThis(function(){window.location.replace();});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhdZa/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for the details here.  Thoughts on `window.location.replace.bind(window.location)`?

Comment: It works, but i prefer to leave the function where it is and just execute it. using an anonymous function also gives you more flexibility and supports more browsers. (Function.prototype.bind is not supported in IE8, and IE8 isn't quite dead just yet.)

Comment: So cool, thank you again for the information.  I'll accept as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this out, using `.bind`

```
doThis(window.location.replace.bind(window.location));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
doThis(function(x) {
    window.location.replace(x);
});
```

or

```
doThis(window.location.replace.bind(window.location));
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var myObj = {
    foo: "foo",
    alert: function(){
       return  alert(this.foo);
    }
}

var a  = myObj.alert(); // "foo"
```

Comment: Please add an explenation how this code works and how it solves the problem

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the question.